# three js object traverse does not update child

Tags: three.js

I traverse child nodes of an object and want to set them visible. But the child is not updated (still visible=false)

```
mymesh.traverse((child) => {
            if (child?.userData?.type === "windowhelper") {
                child.visible = true;
                console.log('child ', child); // prints: child.visible = false !!! why?    
            }
     });
```

Comment: Can you try to log the value instead of the object? Meaning `console.log(child.visible);`? Depending on when you open the console, the object reference has changed and you potentially see a different value.

Comment: this results to true, but the mesh is not visible in the scene

Comment: Any chances to share a live example that shows what you are doing? https://jsfiddle.net/vy29n6aj/